# Testing UIWebView with Xcode UI Testing

Tags: uiwebview, ios9, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I'm using new `Xcode UI Testing` from `XCTest Framework` with the `Xcode 7 GM`. I've got an app with simple UIWebView (it's just a navigation controller + view controller with web view and button) and I want to check following scenario:

1. Web View loads page `www.example.com`
2. User taps on button
3. Web View loads some page with URL: `www.example2.com`

I want to check which page is loaded in UIWebView after pressing button. Is this possible with UI Testing right now?

Actually I'm getting web view like this:

```
let app:XCUIApplication = XCUIApplication()
let webViewQury:XCUIElementQuery = app.descendantsMatchingType(.WebView)
let webView = webViewQury.elementAtIndex(0)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You won't be able to tell *which* page is loaded, as in the actual URL that is being displayed. You can, however, check assert content is on the screen. UI Testing provides a `XCUIElementQuery` for [links that works great with both `UIWebView` and `WKWebView`](http://masilotti.com/ui-testing-cheat-sheet/#how-to-tap-links-in-a-web-view).

Keep in mind that a page doesn't load synchronously, so you will have to [wait for the actual elements to appear](http://masilotti.com/ui-testing-cheat-sheet/#how-to-wait-for-an-element-to-appear).

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.launch()

app.buttons["Go to Google.com"].tap()

let about = self.app.staticTexts["About"]
let exists = NSPredicate(format: "exists == 1")
expectationForPredicate(exists, evaluatedWithObject: about, handler: nil)

waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(5, handler: nil)
XCTAssert(about.exists)

XCTAssert(app.staticTexts["Google Search"].exists)
app.links["I'm Feeling Lukcy"].tap()
```

There is also a [working test host](https://github.com/joemasilotti/UI-Testing-Cheat-Sheet) that goes along with the two links if you want to dig into the code.

Answer (score 3):

If the title of the pages are different, you can check for the title of the web page.

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.launch()
//Load www.example.com

//Tap on some button    
app.links["Your button"].tap()

//Wait for www.example2.com to load
let webPageTitle = app.otherElements["Example2"]
let exists = NSPredicate(format: "exists == 1")
expectationForPredicate(exists, evaluatedWithObject: webPageTitle, handler: nil)
waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(5, handler: nil)
```

Comment: this is great idea, unfortunately I've got one title. But maybe someone will have different situation. Thanks!