# Xcode UI Testing - Finding element in Webview by id

Tags: ios, swift, webview, xcode7, xcode-ui-testing

Our app is hybrid and contains webview.
I'm trying to automate our app using Xcode UI Testing.
I was able to locate web buttons using:

```
let app = XCUIApplication() 
app.launch() 
let button = app.staticTexts["Button's text"]
```

But in one of our tests we test localization - meaning the text changes and the static text query is no longer valid.
Couldn't find any documentation how to locate an element by his id (or even class name). Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32623869/testing-uiwebview-with-xcode-ui-testing/32627868#32627868  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32623869/testing-uiwebview-with-xcode-ui-testing

Comment: Thanks! But this doesn't help. They're talking about using "staticTexts" while my text is dynamic.

Comment: @NirH Did you ever find out how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: @you786 As far as I researched - Not possible out of the box. I eventually kept different languages texts dictionaries for every button.

Answer (score 5):

I have had a similar problem trying to fill in text fields in a `SFSafariViewController`.

I found that using the `aria-label` attribute allowed me to locate elements in the page e.g.

```html
<input role="textbox" aria-label="email" type="email" value="" name="user[email]" id="user_email">
```

And then in your code to select that element

```
webViewsQuery.textFields["email"]
```

Comment: Where did you inspect to get these attributes?

Comment: I couldn't query by textFields in my app, I wish I could.  For some reason the only two things I can query are buttons and staticTexts

Answer (score -5):

By id(ui-test code e.g on swift):

```
    app.buttons["yourBtnAccessibilityId"]
```

this id sets into you *app`s code* (e.g on obj-c) and should be unique.

```
    yourButton.accessibilityIdentifier = @"yourBtnAccessibilityId";
```

By class(ui-test code):

```
    app.buttons.elementBoundByIndex(1)
```

Comment: The question here is clearly about WebViews, not regular buttons on the screen.