# How to access detail disclosure button via identifier under UITests in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, xcode-ui-testing

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let studentsTable = app.tables["studentsTable"]
let detailButton = studentsTable.buttons["More Info, TestName, TestUserName, 2"]
```

It works, but I am pretty sure, there is a more elegant way.

[image]

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/34923025/5135218 (accessibilityIdentifier)

Answer (score 3):

You can access the button directly by setting an accessibility identifier. In your table example you can do so in the table view's data source.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Cell.Identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.accessoryView = UIButton() // your custom button
    cell.accessoryView?.accessibilityIdentifier = "Cell \(indexPath.row + 1) Button"
    return cell
}
```

Then you can tap on each button individually in your UI tests.

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let firstAccessoryButton = app.buttons["Cell 1 Button"]
firstAccessoryButton.tap()
```